# Scrapy - Xpath works in shell but not in code

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm trying to crawl a website (I got their authorization), and my code returns what I want in scrapy shell, but I get nothing in my spider.

I also checked all the previous question similar to this one without any success, e.g., the website doesn't use javascript in the home page to load the elements I need.

```
import scrapy


class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'MySpider'

    start_urls = [ #WRONG URL, SHOULD BE https://shop.app4health.it/ PROBLEM SOLVED!
        'https://www.app4health.it/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        self.logger.info('A response from %s just arrived!', response.url)
        print ('PRE RISULTATI')

        results =  response.selector.xpath('//*[@id="nav"]/ol/li[*]/a/@href').extract()
        # results = response.css('li a>href').extract()


        # This works on scrapy shell, not in code
        #risultati =  response.xpath('//*[@id="nav"]/ol/li[1]/a').extract()
        print (risultati)




        #for pagineitems in risultati:
               # next_page = pagineitems 
        print ('NEXT PAGE')
        #Ignores the request cause already done. Insert dont filter
        yield scrapy.Request(url=risultati, callback=self.prodotti,dont_filter = True)

    def prodotti(self, response):
        self.logger.info('A REEEESPONSEEEEEE from %s just arrived!', response.url)
        return 1
```

The website i'm trying to crawl is https://shop.app4health.it/

The xpath command that i use is this one :

```
response.selector.xpath('//*[@id="nav"]/ol/li[*]/a/@href').extract()
```

I know there are some problems with the **prodotti** function ecc..., but that's not the point. I would like to understand why the xpath selector works with scrapy shell ( i get exactly the links that i need ), but when i run it in my spider, i always get a null list.

If it can help, when i use CSS selectors in my spider, it works fine and it finds the elements, but i would like to use xpath ( i need it in the future development of my application ).

Thanks for the help :)

**EDIT**:
I tried to print the body of the first response ( from start_urls ) and it's correct, i get the page i want. When i use selectors in my code ( even the one that have been suggested ) they all work fine in shell, but i get nothing in my code!

**EDIT 2**
I have become more experienced with Scrapy and web crawling, and i realised that sometimes, the HTML page that you get in your browser might be different from the one you get with the Scrapy request! In my experience some website would respond with a different HTML compared to the one you see in your browser! That's why sometimes if you use the "correct" xpath/css query taken from the browser, it might return nothing if used in your Scrapy code.
Always check if the body of your response is what you were expecting!

**SOLVED**:
Path is correct. I wrote the wrong start_urls!

Comment: Debugging 101. Does scrapy find `//*[@id="nav"]`? If yes, make the expression gradually more complex to find the point where it breaks.

Comment: Could you translate your comments and the variable names? // Potresti tradurre i tuoi commenti e i nomi delle variabili?

Comment: @Tomalak It returns null even with that path! But if i try to debug in scrapy shell, it works fine with that path.

Comment: What is the source code that scrapy is seeing?

Comment: Solved! I wrote the wrong start_urls!

Comment: @MattiaSurricchio please add it as an answer and accept it. It is THE only thing which has helped me after 3 hours of searching and testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively to Desperado's answer you can use css selectors which are much simpler but more than enough for your use case:

```
$ scrapy shell "https://shop.app4health.it/"
In [1]: response.css('.level0 .level-top::attr(href)').extract()
Out[1]: 
['https://shop.app4health.it/sonno',
 'https://shop.app4health.it/monitoraggio-e-diagnostica',
 'https://shop.app4health.it/terapia',
 'https://shop.app4health.it/integratori-alimentari',
 'https://shop.app4health.it/fitness',
 'https://shop.app4health.it/benessere',
 'https://shop.app4health.it/ausili',
 'https://shop.app4health.it/prodotti-in-offerta',
 'https://shop.app4health.it/kit-regalo']
```

`scrapy shell` command is perfect for debugging issues like this.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you suggest me to use CSS selectors instead of xpath? Could you suggest me a good guide to learn how to use them properly? I'm still a novice of web crawling.

Comment: This CSS selector works fine in shell, but not in my code. I think there's something stupid i'm doing wrong in my code, but i don't know what.
I tried to print the initial response body and it works fine, but when i use selectors i always get nothing.

Comment: Well for one your code is crawling `app4health.it` instead of `shop.app4health.it`. Maybe that's the issue? :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    //nav[@id="mmenu"]//ul/li[contains(@class,"level0")]/a[contains(@class,"level-top")]/@href
```

use this xpath, also consider 'view-source' of page before creating xpath

Comment: Could you explain me where i was wrong? I went on the page and copied the xpath from the browser. Why does that path work in scrapy shell but not in my code? 
Thank you so much :)

Comment: I tried this path and i still get null from my selector. Your path works fine in scrapy shell ( as mine ) but both of them don't work in my code. I still can't understand why. 
Could be a problem with xpath in general? 
Thank you so much :)

Comment: can you try response.xpath('//nav[@id="mmenu"]//ul/li[contains(@class,"level0")]/a[contains(@class,"level-top")]/@href').extract()